# Passed variables not working in a specific line

Tags: php

I get the variable in **echo $id;** and the hyperlink can pass the value.

In third line's **id=$id** it is not displaying the value It is directly displaying **$id**.

```
$id= $_GET['id'];
echo $id;
echo '<input type="text" value="localhost/anews/singleeng.php?id=$id" id="myInput">
echo "<a href='generateeng.php?id=$id'> Link </a>";
```

Comment: This code is invalid and generates a parse error. Your second echo (3rd line) is not terminated correctly.

Comment: I made the mistake while posting the question

Answer (score 0):

That's because in the third line you are using a single quote.

In php single quoted strings will display things almost completely "as is." Variables and most escape sequences will not be interpreted.

This should work.

```php
$id = $_GET['id'];
echo '<input type="text" value="localhost/anews/singleeng.php?id='.$id.'" id="myInput">';
```

For more details on single vs double quoted string have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: I made mistake while posting question. My mistake in code was, not using id='.$id.'.